# Reload an HTML element using a java script function?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Well, I am sort of asking a 2 part question but answering either part would help me out. I will be direct in my question and skip straight to what I need help with. I am trying to use a Javascript function to define certain elements of an iframe so the user can decide the source, height, and width. The code I have right now is as shown below.

```js
<script language="javascript">
window.onload = webPage;
 function webPage(){
 var page = prompt("please enter the website","www.google.com");
 var height = prompt("Please enter the height of the frame","800");
 var width = prompt("Please enter the width of the frame","600");
}
</script>
```

```html
<iframe src=page height=height width=width>
</iframe>
```

Is there a way i can reload the iFrame and have it use the user inputs as the elements with my current code? Is there something else that i need to do to have the variables be used for the iFrame? Thanks for anyone who looks at my question and looking forward to your answer.

Comment: You can just dynamically change the `.height`, `.width` and `.src` properties on the iframe.  That will change its size and reload its contents.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Sorry, I am really new to java and not familiar with all the terms and such yet(and how to do stuff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initialize the IFrame with blank values and with one unique **ID** and then append user input.

Here is the working [**`JSFiddle Link`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/6y85fr4f/4/)

**Dynamically Changing Values:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="icereaper666" src="" height="0" width="0"></iframe>
<script language="javascript">
window.onload = webPage;
function webPage(){
    var page = prompt("please enter the website","http://www.w3schools.com/");
    var height = prompt("Please enter the height of the frame","400");
    var width = prompt("Please enter the width of the frame","400");
    var iframeElement = document.getElementById("icereaper666");
    iframeElement.src = page;
    iframeElement.height = height;
    iframeElement.width = width;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** You can also create IFrame element dynamically using **createElement**. [**`Check this out`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/6y85fr4f/3/)

**Using Create Element:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
    window.onload = webPage;
    function webPage(){
        var page = prompt("please enter the website","http://www.w3schools.com/");
        var height = prompt("Please enter the height of the frame","400");
        var width = prompt("Please enter the width of the frame","400");
        var iframeElement = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframeElement.src = page;
        iframeElement.height = height;
        iframeElement.width = width;
        document.body.appendChild(iframeElement);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome, I have copied the same code used above and pasted in the new file and that is working perfectly. May be you should check your console for the errors.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script language="javascript">
window.onload = webPage;
 function webPage(){
 var page = prompt("please enter the website","www.google.com");
 var height = prompt("Please enter the height of the frame","800");
 var width = prompt("Please enter the width of the frame","600");

//new content here
document.getElementById("theIframe").innerHTML="<iframe src=\""+page+"\" height=\""+height+"\" width=\""+width+"\"></iframe>";
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="theIframe"></div>
```

Comment: Why not just modify the iframe object directly?  Why create a whole new one?

Comment: It's either in the script on in the html...no difference really. Explanation also will help Icereaper666 on solving anything else with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RobertCampbell and an explanation of what is going on here and how to load it into a page would be helpful. I only started with programing a few days ago and still don't know much about programming.